# Is there any open source tool to desing mobile application in J2ME?

Tags: java-me

Is there any tool which can help me build J2ME applications in short time?

I dont know J2ME in detail it would be good if by using this tool I can design GUI and can create application in very short time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot of frameworks available for j2me developing. I suggest [LWUIT](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/) is best for developing UI and use the [Resource Editor](http://www.themeswiki.org/Building_themes_using_LWUIT) for design the UI. If You need LWUIT latest source code checkout [here](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/source/browse/lwuit/) and build it. or they officially released [LWUIT 1.4.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/tech/lwuit-141954.html) Some example application available in LWUIT repository and even LWUIT 1.4 package.